# Get Azure oauth token for Power BI Capacity suspend

Tags: azure, api, powerbi-embedded

I need to send Authorisation token for the below Power BI capacity suspend request :

Suspend API CALL :

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/f66cd382-5d26-427e-b345c-d11a6f474740/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.PowerBIDedicated/capacities/%7BdedicatedCapacityName%7D/suspend?api-version=2017-10-01
```

The below API call is used to get Authentication token:
Access token API call :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantId}}/oauth2/token
```

for this access token API call it requires input as grant_type, client_id, client_secret and resource.

My question is that where I need to take client_id and client_secret for Azure power BI embeded type service.

Please give me suggestion

Comment: This may be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53274859/get-authorization-code-for-azure-powerbi-capacity-for-powerbi-embedded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have an App registration to obtain these values. Register an App in Azure AAD.

**Client ID:** Also called the Application ID of the Application that is created to be used with Power BI. Check App registrations in Azure AD.

**Client Secret:** 
This can also be obtained from Azure AAD > App Registrations > Application > Certifications and Secrets.

You also need to Grant access to enable and Grant the PowerBI related API Permissions.