# Getting 403 forbidden from React JS Azure AD token while calling Power Bi Generate token API

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am using Microsoft Azure AD application token to call Power BI Generate token API. Here always i am getting 403 forbidden error. I have given all permissions to my Azure AD application but still getting error

Below is my generated token at Azure AD login

eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkJJRTVzcGkzaS1RbFBUQlBsVTlIQ3RkOFVHa0JJbDdURzdIcW5NTVpkSUEiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImtnMkxZczJUMENUaklmajRydDZKSXluZW4zOCIsImtpZCI6ImtnMkxZczJUMENUaklmajRydDZKSXluZW4zOCJ9.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.aaxcmcIiYV4a4P4DWgwE9YIBykAHpWa7r_sRBgAumOnY1-1qIe3IowQx8jHjUCOWRGiNsKicX8ufk6far3uE2llcAqwzlsVlr36G4oOOdz2Yrd00kv_hI6z-aSjMv_Vdk60MOl0_-4NsY0NtzLi-HTeETSp4EshXc4SLrotLsd1GS-_eavnJ8k-zal0C7QbhgChFZuO_yo-jzX3IdoURqId8sK4gSnNAa46TeyReSjaCz9Uguge9QsBh7Th6b8XFI4BV8fGcJgNG9EzChZVL8eFsofADLM6KJiACVJU8vOFerfOSRiUboMdAlFWQjqI-HaOf_JeS3jxt7pL81v0Mag

getting error in below API with above token, please help

https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/GenerateToken

Is it possible to call Power BI generate token APi using Azure AD token generated by msal library

Answer (score 1):

The audience (`aud`) in tokens that can be used for authorization with Power BI REST API must be `https://analisis.windows.net/powerbi/api`:

[image]

while in your token it is an empty guid:

[image]

Obviously it isn't generated properly. You didn't showed your code, nor mentioned which language is used. See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53274859/get-authorization-code-for-azure-powerbi-capacity-for-powerbi-embedded) how you can do it in C#.

Comment: i am using React JS SPA to generate Azure AD token and used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/register-app URL as a reference to create application. Can you please tell if something is missing in my azure application.  Also, all Power BI permissions are available in application

Comment: It isn’t about the application, but the code where you generate the token. Probably you are passing wrong resource to acquretoken method.

Comment: Yes, the first token (the one you generate with MSAL) is wrong.